# Get a list of numbers that adds up to a number "n" (using repetition of number) - how would one consider the case of using same number multiple times?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, sum, combinations

```
def getList(n, input_list, caching_list):
```

The function should return a list that adds up to a number "n" using numbers from the input_list, given that numbers can be repeated. Looking to use recursion.

current code:

```
def getList(n, input_list, caching_list):
  if n == 0 :
    return caching_list
  if n < 0 or len(input_list) == 0:
    return []

  for i in input_list:
    if find_sum(n-i,input_list,caching_list) == caching_list:
        caching_list.append(i)
        return caching_list
  return []
```

example
n = 13, input_list= [2,3,5] should result in [2,2,2,2,2,3] or [5,5,2] or anything that adds to 13.

Doing this with using a number just 1 time is easy, but how would one consider the case of using same number multiple times?

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your current code that you need assistance with? [ask]

Comment: That was a bad example sorry, i updated it @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: just as a comment your solution looks at least exponential so keep in mind that recursion could end up in stack overflow if given an input the amount of combinations were high.

Answer (score 3):

With recursion, this can be solved using a [depth-first search (DFS) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but it can throw `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

```
def find(n2, plist):
    result = []
    def find2(n):
        if n == 0:
            return True
        if n < 0:
            return False
        for p in plist:
            if find2(n-p):
                result.append(p)
                return True
    find2(n2)
    return result
            
print(find(17, [2,3,5]))       # [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
print(find(7, [3,5]))          # []
print(find(77777, [3,5,7,11])) # recursion error
```

To get rid of the recursion error, recursive DFS can be rewritten into [iterative DFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-depth-first-traversal/).

Answer (score 0):

I find [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) can be very handy for stuff like this. I am sure there are better ways to do it, but this might get you want you need:

```
import itertools

def find_sum(n, p_list):
    max_len = n // min(p_list)
    min_len = n // max(p_list)

    for i in range(min_len, max_len+1):
        I = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(p_list, i)
        for j in I:
            if(sum(j) == n):
                return(list(j))
    return([])

print(find_sum(17,[2,3,5]))
# [2, 5, 5, 5]
print(find_sum(7, [3, 5]))
# []
```

You could easily alter the code to give you all combinations.

```
def find_sum(n, p_list):
    max_len = n // min(p_list)
    min_len = n // max(p_list)
    answers = []
    for i in range(min_len, max_len+1):
        I = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(p_list, i)
        for j in I:
            if(sum(j) == n):
                answers.append(list(j))
    return(answers)
```

```
find_sum(17,[2,3,5])
#[[2, 5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5, 5], [3, 3, 3, 3, 5], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], [2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]]
```

Regarding @dantebarba's comment, I haven't really looked to see how it will scale for large problems and there may be more efficient approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It does seem correct, however i was looking for a recursive solutions. where we try to come up will all combinations and then look for one that adds up.

Comment: Sorry, missed that!

Comment: @DarkIDE `find_sum(n, [x0, x1, x2, ...]) == find_sum(n - x0, [x0, x1, x2, ...]) or find_sum(n, [x1, x2, ...])`

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking @Stef

Comment: @DarkIDE I'm not asking anything. I'm giving a hint. What I wrote is a recursive formula.

Comment: @Stef I don't get it clearly, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @DarkIDE What is it that you "don't get"? Do you not understand why that formula is true? Or do you not understand why a recurrence formula can help you write code?

Comment: yes the formula doesnt make sense to me. @Stef. how would it consider the repeat of same numbers or if it uses 2,2,2 and output is 7, it can never get 2.2.3 after

Comment: @DarkIDE The formula basically says "To make `n` with the numbers in the list, either I use `x0`, or I don't". So there are two recursive calls, one for the case where we use `x0` at least once, and one for the case where we don't use `x0` at all. Notice that if I choose not to use `x0` at all, then `x0` is removed from the list in the recursive call; but if I choose to use `x0`, then `x0` is not removed from the list, so it can be used again.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 lines of code should raise some red flags:

```py
if find_sum(n-i,p,p_list,sum_list) == sum_list:
    sum_list.append(i)
    return sum_list
```

You have a recursive function storing its results in `sum_list`, modifying it, and also depending on its values for equality checks. This makes your program extremely difficult to reason about. Does the behavior change if you swap the arguments around the equality sign? I have no idea.

In general, your recursive programs should try to avoid passing their result as a parameter. Since that `if` statement is really asking whether we can make a certain sum, why not break that into a separate function?

```py
def can_sum(n, p_list, cache={}):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n == 0:
        return True
    if n < 0:
        return False
    return any(can_sum(n-p, p_list) for p in p_list)
```

You want to use some kind of caching (otherwise, your program is exponential-time), and `functools.cache` is preferable if you can use outside libraries, but this will do the job.

How should your `find_sum` function return results without passing the result as a parameter? Just add your value to the end, exactly like your code did:

```py
def find_sum(n, p_list):
    for p in p_list:
        if can_sum(n-p, p_list):
            return find_sum(n-p, p_list) + [p]
    return []
```